# How are there $10^4$ ways to choose the 4 digits?

Tags: probability

In a lottery, players win a large prize when they pick four digits that match, in the correct order,
four digits selected by a random mechanical process.A smaller prize is won if only three digits
are matched. What is the probability that a player wins the large prize? What is the probability
that a player wins the small prize?

- Solution: There is only one way to choose all four digits correctly. By the product rule, there
  are $10^4 = 10,000$ ways to choose four digits. Hence, the probability that a player wins the large
  prize is $\frac{1}{10000} = 0.0001$.

How are there $10^4$ ways to choose the 4 digits? What is 10 here??

Comment: The answer assumes, not unreasonably, that digits can repeat, so $0406$ is a possibility. There are $10$ ways to choose the first digit. For each of these, there are $10$ ways to choose the second digit. And so on.

Comment: The number $10$ counts (I hope) your fingers = digits. Can you imagine $0000$, $0001$, $0002$, $\ldots,9999$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How many options do you have for the first digit? 10 options. 
How many for the second digit, again 10 options. 
So for the first two digits you have 10^2 options, and hence for four digits you have 10^4 options.

Comment: It is not coming into my mind that how are there 10 ways to choose a digit? Can you give an example of one digit with 10 ways?

Comment: @user249818 Easy, 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 or 9. There are 10 ways to choose one digit.

Comment: What about the order? Why are we not applying any combination formula here?

Comment: @user249818 Since the order of the numbers is important, i.e. 34 and 43 count as different numbers, we don't need to consider permutations of the digits.

Comment: @user249818 There's only one way to order one thing. But with four things order does matter. You choose the first digit, which has 10 choices, then second, then third and forth. So you have 10^4 choices.

Comment: What is the probability that a person picks the correct six numbers out of 40?
Solution: There is only one winning combination. The total number of ways to choose six numbers out of 40 is
C(40, 6) = 40!/34! 6!
= 3,838,380.
Consequently, the probability of picking a winning combination is 1/3,838,380 ≈ 0.00000026.                                                                          I don't under stand that in that question we were randomly picking and in this we are picking out of 40,how is the probability smaller then being pick randomly?

Comment: @user249818 In that question it doesn't matter which numbers are picked first, so picking a 5 then a 12 would be the same as picking a 12 then a 5, hence you have to account for permutations. In this question if the order mattered and you could pick the same number twice, for each number there would be 40 choices, so there would be a total of 40^6 possibilities.

Comment: Now I understand,order is not mattering in the 2nd example. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

10 is the number of digits that exists (there are 10 numbers from 0 to 9 inclusive).

Consider the four digit number as determined by 4 blanks. Because there are 10 numbers that could go in each of the 4 spaces, there are $10^4$ ways to pick a number. You could also see that there are 10000 possible numbers between 0000 and 9999 inclusive.

Another way to think about it would be the inductive reasoning. There are $10^4$ ways to pick a 4 digit number. What happens if we added another digit (so we had to pick a 5 digit number)? We would have all the possibilities of four digit numbers and a 0 at the end, all the possibilities of four digit numbers and a 1 at the end, etc. so there would be $10\cdot x$ where $x$ is the number of ways to pick 4. Then by induction we can verify that $10^n$ is the number of ways to pick $n$-digit numbers.